# Copy entire directory with button from two dynamic locations

Tags: c#, dynamic, directory, copy

Okay, I have a button (button1) which I want to copy the static directory to the chosen directory. Essentially I have textbox1 in which different numeric values are added which correlate with different directories. I have a dictionary that sets the string to mapping which links to codes from textbox2 to the path of the origination folder. . This determines where we copy our data from. I want this data to then be copied into the folder selected in textbox2  through the folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog(); command. how to i create the dictionary and where do i put it for textbox1, and how do i then get the button to take whatever is in textbox1 and copy the entire directory to textbox2?

```
private Dictionary<string, string> mapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "111", @"C:\Program Files\Example" },
    { "112", @"C:\Program Files\Example2" },
    { "113", @"C:\Program Files\Example3" },
};

public static string[] GetFiles(string mapping);

public static void Copy(string sourceFileName, string destFileName);

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string destination = textBox1.Text;

    foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(mapping))
    {
        File.Copy(Path.Combine(mapping, f)); destination;
    }
}
```

Comment: Too many questions at once, too many details. Focus on one step at a time. AND PLEASE: fix the formatting in your code sample.

Comment: @DrKoch if you read carefully you will notice it is one question with the objective as follows. Use button1 to copy the directory from the mapping dictionary output to the textbox1 input. That is it. I guarantee it is no more than 10 lines of code which is so much harder to explain in 3 separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answeer to "How copy an entire directory of files":

Use `Directory.GetFiles()` (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to get a list of all files in a directory.

Then use `File.Copy()` (see [documenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to copy a single file:

```
foreach(var f in Directory.GetFiles(srcPath))
{
    File.Copy(Path.Combine(srcPath, f), dstPath);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

`Directory.GetFiles()` requires a path:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string destination = textBox1.Text;
    string srcdir = mapping["111"];
    foreach(var f in Directory.GetFiles(srcdir))
    {
         string srcpath = Path.Combine(srcdir, f)
         File.Copy(srcpath, destination);
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the source above, but I am getting a context error for Directory. Is there a designation I am supposed to add to the Directory? or is that supposed to link to a string I am supposed to set somewhere? Im sorry, its just a little confusing here haha

Comment: If you follow the documenattion link in my answer you'll see the info `Namespace:  System.IO` this means you need a using directive `using System.IO;` at the beginning of your code in order to use the `Directory` class. Also, Visual Studio should hint you at this.

Comment: Also: please fix the formatting of your code. It hurts in the eyes and will introduce a lot of hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: I'm used to python and javascript so this isn't really my game, sorry to formatting is funky. As for the code you provided, it is riddled with errors according to VB. apparently it expects a ; behind dstPath); which makes absolutely no sense. can you use the source code at the top of the page to show me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: My code compiles! Please learn enough C# to make your code compile. Fix the formatting.

Comment: So then what looks wrong with my code above. And your code sure as hell doesn't compile, you didn't even type Directory correctly. I get that the spacing is weird but it compiles perfectly fine in every aspect but this.

Comment: @JoePearson - "As for the code you provided, it is riddled with errors according to **VB**".  The above code (and the code you posted) is C#, **NOT** VB.  If you're trying to compile it as VB, it's no surprise it's not compiling.

Comment: Typo, I meant VS (Visual Studio)

Comment: The original code posted (which may have been a typo) would indeed not compile.  `File.Copy(Path.Combine(srcPath, f)), dstPath);` has an extra parentheses after `f`,  It should be `File.Copy(Path.Combine(srcPath, f), dstPath);`.  I'm willing to bet it was a typo in posting :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understood the details of your question, as the uses of TextBox1 and TextBox2 don't seem consistent, but here's what I read:

- TextBox1 has the codes that the dictionary maps to a source directory.
- TextBox2 has the path (from the dialog box) to the destination directory.

If that is correct, you're close. Some things to note:

1. I'm not sure why you have these two lines.  They look like method definitions, but there's no implementation.  I think you can remove them and use the equivalent `System.IO` calls:

   `public static string[] GetFiles(string mapping);`

   `public static void Copy(string sourceFileName, string destFileName);`
2. `Directory.GetFiles(mapping)` won't work, because `mapping` is a `Dictionary<string, string>`, not a `string`.  You need to select the corresponding value (path) based on the key (numeric code) from `TextBox1` and use that in the `Directory.GetFiles()` method.
3. `File.Copy(Path.Combine(mapping, f)); destination;` is an incorrect syntax and won't compile (should be `File.Copy(Path.Combine(mapping, f), destination);`.  Additionally, you don't need to combine the source path and filename for the first argument, as `GetFiles` returns the path along with the filename (including extension).  You will need to get the filename alone and combine it with the sourece path for the destination file, however.  You can use [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this.

Try this code below - it addresses the issues noted above, with the assumption being that `textBox1` is the source in mappings and `textBox2` is the destination from the dialog window:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string source = textBox1.Text
    string destination = textBox2.Text;

    if (mappings.ContainsKey(source))
    {
        foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(source))
        {
            File.Copy(f, Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(f)));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // No key was found, how you handle it will be dictated by the needs of the application and/or users.
    }
}
```

The above code does the following:

1. Gets the numeric value for the path of the source directory.  This should correspond to one of the keys in the dictionary.
2. Gets the path for the destination directory based on the user selected value from the dialog box.
3. Checks to see if the key from `textBox1` is present in the directory.
4. If it is, it gets the corresponding value for that key, which is the path for the source directory.
5. Next, it loops through the files in the specified source directory, copying each one in turn to the destination directory.  Note that `f` (the file) is used as the source file for the first argument (as it contains the path as well, as `Directory.GetFiles()` returns both the path and the filename), and the destination directory is combined with the filename (retrieved by a call to `Path.GetFileName`).  If `f` alone was used in the `Path.Combine()` method, you'd wind up with `sourcePath\originalPath\filename`.
6. If the key wasn't found, you ignore it or do something with it.

Again, the above code is based on my understanding of your question.  If my understanding was less than correct, the principles I outlined should still be able to assist you in resolving the issue.

** EDIT **

Per the comments below, it sounds like all you need to do is flip the assignments for `source` and `destination`.  `textBox2` will contain the code that corresponds to a key in the `mappings` directory, which will give you the path of the source directory.  `textBox1` will contain the destination path.  Like this:

```
string source = textBox2.Text
string destination = textBox1.Text;
```

The rest of the code stays the same.

Comment: This is awesome @Tim, how would I go about setting mapping as the source and textbox1 and the destination?

Comment: @JoePearson - as long as you now the key for the mapping, you can use that to get the value for the source, and then the destination would take the value from `textBox1` instead of `textBox2`.

Comment: I'm sorry man, I am unbelievably new to C#, what do you mean by key? essentially what I have is a value in textbox2 that is generated by selections from comboboxes. Each code that is generates will be associated with a different file in mapping. Textbox1 is where the user can select where they want the folder from mapping to go. Button2 is what would activate the move from mapping to the folder designated in textbox1. I hope I make sense to you because reading it back confuses me lol.

Comment: Got it.  By key I mean the key in the Dictionary - the first item.  The second item is the value associated with that key.  So if textbox2 has the code that corresponds to the mapping for the source directory and textbox1 has the directory for the destination, all you need to do is swap the assignments of `source` and `destination` and adjust the code accordingly.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Looks like everything is compiling correctly! I am getting an odd error when I run the button2 function. I will post in a moment.